# Iterate over returned angular resource in controller

Tags: angularjs, mapping, angular-promise

I have a controller that accesses a resource `Tag` like so:

```
$scope.tags = Tag.query();
```

which resolves to something *like* this:

```
$scope.tags = [
  { name: "tag1", label: "Tag1" },
  { name: "tag2", label: "Tag2" },
  { name: "tag3", label: "Tag3" },
  { name: "tag4", label: "Tag4" },
];
```

For this particular controller, the returned tags should have an additional attribute `"active": true`, like `{ name: "tag1", label: "Tag1", active: true }`.

**How can I iterate over the returned promise once it is resolved to add this boolean?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the promise.then() function.

```
Tag.query().$promise.then(function (results) {
    angular.forEach(results, function (result) {
        result.active = true;
    });

    $scope.tags = results
});
```

see the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) on $q

Comment: One more implementation comment, the $resource returns a $promise first, so the first line should be `Tag.query().$promise.then(...`

Comment: Can someone update the answer's code to add $promise?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is this:

```
$scope.tags = Tag.query(function() {
    $scope.tags['active'] = true;
});
```

When the server finishes calling the function that adds the property is executed.

I recommend you read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: I think you want active property ownership in each tag, and not as a property of the tags. Note this, because if so my answer may be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I need all objects in the tags array to have the attribute.